# POST to Sinatra always returns 200

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger

I have the code below and even when it goes into the `rescue` block it ignores the `status 500` and always returns a 200 response code... what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
post /deletebranch do
  # setup my variables here
  if checkout_sha.eql? '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    delete_branch(endpoint, repo_path, config_obj)
  end
end

def delete_branch(endpoint, repo_path, config_obj)
    base = config_obj['base_dir']
    if Dir.exists?(base) and Dir.exists?("#{base}/#{repo_path}")
      stream do |body_content|
        body_content << "endpoint:  #{endpoint}\n"
        body_content << "repo_path: #{repo_path}\n"
        body_content << "base:      #{base}\n"
        body_content << "\n"

        body_content << "Attempting to remove '#{repo_path}' from inside '#{base}'\n"
        logger.info("Attempting to remove '#{repo_path}' from inside '#{base}'")

        begin
          Dir.chdir(base)
          FileUtils.remove_entry_secure(repo_path, force = false)
        rescue => e
          logger.info('This exception was thrown:')
          logger.error(e)
          body_content << 'This exception was thrown:'
          body_content << e
          body_content << "\n"
          status 500
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try putting your `delete_branch` function inside a `helpers do..end` block.

Comment: @mwp - Unfortunately, wrapping it in a `helpers do..end` block didn't change anything.

Comment: Try `halt 500` instead of `status 500`. That should actually terminate route processing.

Comment: Switching to `halt 500` actually broke the error handling done in the rescue block even when the halt is outside the `begin...rescue`. The message says that there was an `uncaught throw :halt`. I even tried putting in an `error do..end` like the Sinatra docs say to do... same deal.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the response code (`200`, `500` etc.) after you've begun to return the response body. Because you are using `stream` it means you've been sending the response body to the browser far before your code hits `status 500`, and the response code *must* come before the body.

It seems that you are sending a very small amount of data, so you don't need to stream at all. Try doing something as follows:

```
post '/deletebranch' do
  # setup my variables here
  if checkout_sha.eql? '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    delete_branch(endpoint, repo_path, config_obj)
  end
end

def delete_branch(endpoint, repo_path, config_obj)
    base = config_obj['base_dir']

    status_code = 200
    body_content = ""

    if Dir.exists?(base) and Dir.exists?("#{base}/#{repo_path}")
      body_content << "endpoint:  #{endpoint}\n"
      body_content << "repo_path: #{repo_path}\n"
      body_content << "base:      #{base}\n"
      body_content << "\n"

      body_content << "Attempting to remove '#{repo_path}' from inside '#{base}'\n"
      logger.info("Attempting to remove '#{repo_path}' from inside '#{base}'")

      begin
        Dir.chdir(base)
        FileUtils.remove_entry_secure(repo_path, force = false)
      rescue => e
        logger.info('This exception was thrown:')
        logger.error(e)
        body_content << 'This exception was thrown:'
        body_content << e
        body_content << "\n"
        status_code = 500
      end
    end

    [status_code, body_content]
end
```